# Считать новый URL на который был редирект

Tags: php, curl, url

Пытаюсь авторизироваться через Вконтакте, и мне вк выдает ошибку №17.

https://vk.com/dev/need_validation

Окей, не беда. Но вот в чем беда наступает, так это когда я перехожу по ссылке вида:

```
https://m.vk.com/login?act=security_check&api_hash=4a959bd2a221c
```

И вк если все успешно, меня редиректит на

```
https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#success=1&access_token=новый_токен&user_id=ид_юзера
```

Я работаю через curl, как мне после редиректа считать этот новый URL адрес?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Подробнее тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519939/make-curl-follow-redirects